# Phone does not detect SIM after a few minutes

Tags: rom-flashing

I have a Moto G (Falcon). I have flashed some custom ROMs on it over the past few years, but there is one problem which always persists. When I restart the phone or turn off the airplane mode, the phone detects the SIM for a few minutes and everything works perfectly.

After some time, it shows the message 
"invalid card" . I tried multiple SIMS in either of the slots, but the problem persists. The problem wasn't there with the stock ROM.

Did I mess up with something while flashing the ROMs? If not,  does anyone have an idea why is this happening ?